# Imported function is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a little unfamiliar with ES6, so I'm not entirely sure what my issue is here.

I have the following code;

```
const isUsernameTaken = username => {
    console.log(username);
}


exports = {
    isUsernameTaken
}
```

And it is imported by another file, like so;

```
import {isUsernameTaken} from "./Client"
```

However, if I try to use it, I get an error stating that Object is not a function. If I do console.log(isUsernameTaken), it's returning undefined. I'm not 100% sure what the issue is, here.

Comment: just `export const isUsernameTaken...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports = {}` is the wrong syntax. To create default / named exports, use the following.

#### Named Export

```
const isUsernameTaken = username => {
    console.log(username);
}


export { isUsernameTaken }
```

Then your import should work as expected.

```
import { isUsernameTaken } from "./Client"
```

#### Default Export

Default exports allow you to suppress the `{}` from the statement and *should* be used *if* your module only has one export.

```
export default const isUsernameTaken = username => {
    console.log(username);
}
```

Then import like so.

```
import isUsernameTaken from "./Client"
```

*Note: notice the missing `{}` - this only works with **default** exports*

For reference, refer to the [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) docs.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I've used default exports in the past, just not named exports, and I couldn't figure it out with ES6.

Answer (score 1):

1. `exports` is CommonJS-specific. Instead, you shall do `export { isUsernameToken };`.
2. Even if you have CommonJS/harmony compatibility in place, assignments directly to the `exports` variable is ignored since its value is not used. You normally assign to `module.exports` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
const isUsernameTaken = username => {
    console.log(username);
}


export default isUsernameTaken;
```

And then use it like:

```
import isUsernameTaken from "./Client"
```

Hope this works for you.